Notion converts timestamps in current timezone. How to display them in local timezone and mention the timezone along with the timestamp
I am creating an itinerary page for my upcoming travel which will commence in another timezone. Now when I put the time stamps in the text, I can put them as local time in that timezone by selecting the timezone manually. But Notion displays them converted in my current time zone, which is confusing at times.
For example, say I am in EST, and I want to set a reminder on December 25, 2024 12:00 PM in PST. It shows up for me as December 25, 2024 3:00 PM. Which is confusing. Is there a way to display the timestamp in its local timezone along with the timezone? That is I want it to be shown as December 25, 2024 12:00 PM (PST).
I remember Notion allowed this a long time ago. But I can't find the setting anymore. Is there a way to remove this confusion?

What is Notion? (The tag is empty.)

It is a productivity application that people use to manage tasks, document events, etc. - notion.so
